# angular laravel crud pivot relation many to many role user

Tags: angular, laravel, pivot, ngfor

**Hello community**, I am stuck on how to add a role for multiple users and vice versa, to do a test,

1.I created my front-end with Angular which shows me the list of
roles for each user and

2. with Laravel I created an api with a crud for user and another for role in their controller, the api routes requests have been tested with Postman and work well, I have configured a .env in local mysql phpmyadmin, a role_user pivot table, and the users and roles models which contains the belongsToMany relationships,
3. I created a component role with its .html and its .ts,
4. a button created via a form allows to create and display a role, but I cannot assign a role to a user
5. however I would like to understand how to display create modify delete roles for specific users with Angular 12 and Laravel 8 ?

**NB: I detail the files concerned.**

***Thank you in advance for your precious help !***

[frontend angular create and display role for user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa7E9.jpg)

role-list.component.html :

```
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
<app-nav></app-nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header-tab card-header">
                    <h3>ROLE</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body"> 
                    <!--  -->
                        <form [formGroup]="newFormGroup">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
                                    <label for="validationName" class="form-label">User</label>
                                    <input type="name" formControlName="name" class="form-control"
                                        id="validationName" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                            
                                <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
                                    <label for="validationAdresse" class="form-label">Role</label>
                                    <input type="name" formControlName="role" class="form-control"
                                        id="validationAdress" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>                         
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-2" (click)="insertRole()">Create</button>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">{{ Role }} </th>
            <th scope="col">{{ User }}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!--  -->
        <tr *ngFor="let role of roles">
            <th scope="row">{{ role.id }}</th>  
            <td>{{ role.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ role.id }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

role-list.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Pudo } from 'src/app/pudo';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-role-list',
  templateUrl: './role-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./role-list.component.scss']
})
export class RoleListComponent implements OnInit {

  newFormGroup: FormGroup;
  roles: Object;
  User: string = 'User';
  Role: string = 'Role';
  
  constructor(private api:ApiService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllRole();
    this.initForm();
  }

  getAllRole() {
    this.api.get('roles').subscribe(resp => {
      this.roles = resp;
      console.log(resp);
    });
  }

  initForm() {
    this.newFormGroup = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl("",[Validators.required,]),
    })
  }

  insertRole() {
    let name = this.newFormGroup.get('name').value;
       
    let dataForm = {
      user_id: localStorage.getItem('id'),
      "name" : name,
    }
    
    this.api.post('roles', dataForm).subscribe(resp => {
      console.log("dataForm", dataForm);
      this.roles = resp;
      this.getAllRole();
    })
  }
}
```

api.service.ts :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.setHeadersBasicOptions();
    this.setHeadersPaginateOptions();
  }
  
  //Http Options
  httpOptions = {}

  //HttpHeaders Options
  headersBasic: HttpHeaders;
  headersPaginate: HttpHeaders;

  setHeadersBasicOptions() {
    console.log('setHeadersOptions lancé')
    this.headersBasic = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
      'paginate' : '0'
    })
  }

  setHeadersPaginateOptions() {
    this.headersPaginate = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
      'paginate' : '1'
    })
  }

  get(url) {
    return this.httpClient.get(API_URL+url, {headers:this.headersBasic});
  }

  getReportById(id) {
    return this.httpClient.get(API_URL+'employees/'+id, {headers:this.headersBasic});
  }

  updateData(id, data) {
    return this.httpClient.post(API_URL+'employees/'+id, data, {headers:this.headersBasic});
  }

  // paginate(url) {
  //   return this.httpClient.get(API_URL+url, {headers:this.headersPaginate});
  // }

  // filter(url, data) {
  //   return this.httpClient.post(API_URL+url, data, {headers:this.setHeadersPaginateOptions});
  // }

  post(url, data) {
    return this.httpClient.post(API_URL+url, data, {headers:this.headersBasic});
  }

  delete(url) {
    return this.httpClient.delete(API_URL + url, {headers:this.headersBasic});
  }

  //Error handling
  handleError(error) {
    let errorMessage = '';
      if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        //Get client-side error
        errorMessage = error.error.message;
      }else{
        //Get server-side error
        errorMessage = 'Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}';
      }
      window.alert(errorMessage);
      return throwError(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

UserController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable ;
    
    public function getAll(){
        
        $users = User::with(["userType"])->get();
        
        return Response::json($users, 200);
    }

    public function getById($id){
        $user = User::with(["userType"])->find($id);
        return Response::json($user, 200);
    }

    public function create(Request $request){
        
        $user = new User;
        
        $user = User::new($user, $request);

        return Response::json($user, 200);
    }

    public function update($id, Request $request){
        $user = User::find($id);
        
        $user = User::new($user, $request);
        
        return Response::json($user, 200);
    }

    public function delete($id){
        
        User::destroy($id);
        
        return Response::json("supression validée", 200);
    }
    
    public function login(Request $request){
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            // Authentication passed...
            $success['id'] =  $user->id;
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('Laravel')->accessToken; 
            $success['email'] =  $user->email;
            $success['password'] =  $user->password;
 
            return response()->json($success, 200); 
        } else {
            return Response::json('unauthorized', 401);
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        if(Auth::check()):
            Auth::user()->token()->delete();
        endif;

        return Response::json("vous avez été déconnecté", 200);
    }

    
}
```

RoleController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class RoleController extends Controller
{
    public function getAll(){
        
        $roles = Role::all();
        
        return Response::json($roles, 200);
    }

    public function getById($id){
        $role = Role::find($id);
        
        return Response::json($role, 200);
    }

    public function create(Request $request){
        
        $role = new Role;
        
        $role = Role::new($role, $request);

        return Response::json($role, 200);
    }

    public function update($id, Request $request){
        $role = Role::find($id);
        
        $role = Role::new($role, $request);
        
        return Response::json($role, 200);
    }

    public function delete($id){
        
        Role::destroy($id);
        
        return Response::json("supression validée", 200);
    }
}
```

Model User :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'email',
        'password',
        'user_type_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token'
    ];

    public static function new($user, $request){

        $user->firstname = $request->firstname;
        $user->lastname = $request->lastname;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = $request->password;
        $user->user_type_id = $request->user_type_id;

        if($request->password && $request->password == $request->confirm_password):
            $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        endif;

        $user->save();

        return $user;
    }

    public function userType(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\UserType');
    }

    public function basic_infos() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\BasicInfo');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role');
    } 
}
```

Model Role :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Role extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public static function new($role, $request){
        
        $role->name = $request->name;      

        $role->save();

        return $role;
    }

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

create_role_user_table.php :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateRoleUserTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your question, we have to first think of the db architecture. Now you have two tables of User and Roles. As I observed, you are going to keep the user role in user table. However, if you want to assing **one** user role to **many** users, then you need to have a third table to hold the relationship. Update your laravel cord accordingly.

In angular side, you can try a dialog component to give a better user experiance. Check on [angular material](https://material.angular.io/) for pre-defined UI component set.